# How can I change footer background color?

Tags: background, footer

Ive tried to change this footers background color, but to no avail. How can I change the background color on this footer? Please be specific because I am not a clever man. I included some CSS that isn't relevant but thought it was necessary.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif, arial ;
background-color: #C2A366;
margin: 0 auto;
p.padding
{
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-left:0px;
}
table {
margin: 5px;
padding: 0;
}
}
#push{height:80px}

#footer{padding-top:0px; border-top:0px solid #dadada; width:960px; margin:0px auto 0;         height:0px; color:#4d4d4d;}

#footer p{font-size:1.2em; color:#4d4d4d; line-height:1.5em; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:0.6em}

.copyrightbar {
margin: 0 auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
</style> 


<div class="push"></div>
</div> <!--Page Wrap-->
    <div id="footer">
   <table class="copyrightbar">
<tr><td><p class="padding"><font color="white">Phone: 555-555-1800<br>hello</p></font>        </td>
<td> <p> <font color="white"> Sample text<br></font>
</td></tr>
  </table><table> <br>
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <p align="center"><font color="white" font size="2">                 <i>Copyright &copy All Rights Reserved. </i> </font></p>
    <div class="push"></div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</div>
</body></table>
</html>
```

Comment: background-color:tomato; would do for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `background-color:`color`;` in `#footer` in your CSS.
I have applied `background-color:red;` in your CSS.

Here is your code with background color : http://jsfiddle.net/992fK/

But, in this case, you have put all your contents inside `<div id="footer">`, that's why the background color is applied to all the contents. You can arrange your contents so that only footer contents will come inside footer div an then color will be applied as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `background-color` property in your `#footer`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use background-color property in the css or style. Mark it !important to avoid any type of confliction from another same property.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your `HTML` code to the following

```
    <div class="push"></div>
    <!--Page Wrap-->
    <div id="footer">
    <table class="copyrightbar">
       <tr>
          <td>
            <p class="padding">
              <font color="white">Phone: 555-555-1800<br>hello</br>
              </font>
            </p>        
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>
              <font color="white"> 
                <br>Sample text</br>
              </font>
            </p>
         </td></tr>
    </table>

    <table> 
      <br/>
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
        <p align="center">
           <font color="white" font size="2">
                 <i>Copyright &copy All Rights Reserved. </i>
           </font>
        </p>
        <div class="push"></div>
        <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </table>
```

and to add `background-color:color;` in `#footer` in your `CSS` as @Beauflitz said